# How to make multiple search conditions on same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get results from my database with a "where" compound if possible.

My Table `answers` looks like:

```
id | user_id | question_id | answers
------------------------------------
1  |   111   |     123     | meat
2  |   111   |     124     | good
3  |   111   |     125     | 8
4  |   112   |     123     | salad
5  |   112   |     124     | bad
6  |   112   |     125     | 3
7  |   113   |     123     | meat
8  |   113   |     124     | good
9  |   113   |     125     | 10
```

I tried using "where in" but it doesn't solve the whole problem.
Also i tried to do something like this code but doesn't work. Always returns `0`.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(answers.user_id)) FROM answers
WHERE (answers.question_id = '123' AND answers.answer = 'meat')
AND (answers.question_id = '124' AND answers.answer = 'good')
AND (answers.question_id = '125' AND answers.answer > 7);
```

The result should be "2" because there are 2 user_id that meet all the requirements.

Comment: You possibly need `OR` instead of `AND` in the conditions: `(....) OR (....) ...`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `OR` on outer conditions:

```
WHERE (answers.question_id = '123' AND answers.answer = 'meat')
OR (answers.question_id = '124' AND answers.answer = 'good')
OR (answers.question_id = '125' AND answers.answer > 7);
```

The way you have it, `question_id` would have to equal to 123, 124, 125 at once! WWhich is not possible :) Thus, you're getting wrong results.

Comment: Hi Michal. Thanks a lot for your response. What if i need that the COUNT returns only if ALL conditions to match. That's why i use "AND" instead of "OR". In my example should return "2", but suppose that the row whose "ID" is 9 (the last one) contains the number "3", in this case I would like the "COUNT" to be 1, but with "OR" it would give 2.

Comment: It's like i want to group this conditional --> WHERE (answers.question_id = '123' AND answers.answer = 'meat') <-- so i can put "AND" with the same columns.